# Application_Start and RabbitMQ

Tags: asp.net-mvc, rabbitmq, domain-driven-design

We have an ASP.NET MVC application that needs to take the data from a RabittMQ queue, but the implementation of connection and consumer are in domain layer because the data received are domain data.

So we need to start this connection/consumer from the presentation layer (through an application service), and that process must be running continuously to cache the information.

Is this approach correct within a DDD architecture? How do we start this consumer from MVC layer through the application service?

Comment: "the implementation of connection and consumer are in domain layer"  That's likely a failure to separate your concerns properly.

Comment: @VoiceOfUnreason, what do you propose? Thanks!

Comment: Nobody? I need help...

Answer (score 1):

Sending and receiving messages through a message queue is an Infrastructure concern. Then incoming messages can be handled exactly like you would any input coming from the UI, by calling the next layer in the chain i.e. Application.